# ng2-smart-table using ServerDataSource data not changing when navigate page

Tags: json, angular, ng2-smart-table

i'm using ng2-smart-table with ServerDataSource like this

```
this.source = new ServerDataSource(_http, {
  dataKey: 'data.data', 
  endPoint: 'https://myapi?page=', 
  pagerPageKey: 'data.meta.current_page',
  pagerLimitKey: 'data.meta.per_page',
  totalKey: 'data.meta.total',
});
```

on my url i got this `http://localhost:4200/pages/admin/users-list?page=1` but it doesn't change when i navigate the pages even if i change the url to other page. It's working if i change my api from `https://myapi?page=1` to `https://myapi?page=2` i know i did something wrong but where is it?

EDIT

I don't know if this will work but i think i need to get the "current page" by listening to page change event. So for now i have this code:

```
this.source.onChanged().subscribe((change) => {
  if (change.action === 'page') {
    this.page = change.paging.page;
    this.userService.getAllUser(this.page).subscribe(
      (data:any)=>console.log(data.data.data)
    )
  }
});
```

i got a result just like i wanted, but the problem is how can i use the `this.page` to `myapi?page=`. anyone have a solution?

EDIT

```
this.source = new ServerDataSource(_http, {
  dataKey: 'data.data', 
  endPoint: 'https://myapi', 
  pagerPageKey: 'page',
  totalKey: 'data.meta.total',
});
```

Comment: did you set up your angular router to accept page ids ? maybe you can share your routing setup

Comment: after looking around, the given url is not form `ServerDataSource` it's from my api. So ServerDataSource doesn't use queryParams i guess. but still i can't navigate the page

Comment: also i searched in akveo github issues, i found this https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/projects/demo/src/app/pages/examples/server/serve.data-source.ts but i don't know if its relevant

Comment: this.page is number of the page ? or does it containe the number of the page ?

Comment: yes `this.page` is thenumber of the page

Comment: but i think i can't use ng2 smart table with for this, my backend set the data to be only displayed 10 per page, to get other data i need to use page params, if u know a library which suitable for this pls let me know

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to change your page params in Data source config object

```
 this.source = new ServerDataSource(_http, 
{
dataKey: 'data.data',
endPoint: 'https://myapi/endpoint',
pagerPageKey: 'page', // this should be page number param name in endpoint (request not response) for example 'page'
pagerLimitKey: 'your-endpoint-param-name-for-pageSize', // this should page size param name in endpoint (request not response)
totalKey: 'data.meta.total', // this is total records count in response , key seems right 
});
```

so you need to change pagerPageKey value to 'page' and pagerpagelimit to your key in endpoint

no any need to handle this.source.onChanged()  // remove this code

Comment: if my backend accept this `myendpoint.com/api/data?page=1` how should i set it to the config?

Comment: you should pass the object the same as above answer, according to your url  params you should set param 'pagerPageKey' with value 'page' ,,, 'endPoint' to 'http://myendpoint.com/api/data' ,,,  'dataKey' to your data path in response let us say 'data.records',,, 'totalKey' to your records total count path returned in response like 'data.totalcount'

Comment: sorry for late response, after i read it again i think i missed understanding your answer. what youre saying with "request not response" it's for my config, i didn't realize that after i read it again

Comment: ive edited my question according to your answer, is that correct? i dont need pagerLimitKey so i removed it

Comment: yes, your config is correct according your url, 
you can ignore 'pagerLimitKey' if it set from server 'static' , you should remove onsourceChanged , pagination will be handled automatically from serverDataSource,  
still have any problems ?

Comment: from your config it shows that your returned object from server like this: 
{ "data" :  { "data" : yourList[] , "meta" : { "total" : 100 } } }    
,right ?

Comment: it should work correctly, still have any other problems ?